# MariaDB/ MySQL : Syntax error in cross join with multiple select

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a procedure with a cross join with 2 selects. In the first select I select the price value where the `vitamin_name` contains `extreme` which is not null and in the second select I select the price value where the `vitamin_name` does not contain `extreme` which is not null. I cross join those selects but I keep getting syntax error at line 9. I have no idea what I did wrong in line 9. How should it be?

```
table = vitamin
+----------------+-------+
|  vitamin_name  | price |
+----------------+-------+
| extreme pill 1 |    10 |
| pill 1         |     5 |
| extreme pill 2 |    20 |
| pill 2         |    10 |
+----------------+-------+
```

My code

```
BEGIN

SELECT sel_extreme.ext, sel_regular.reg FROM

(SELECT sel.extreme as 'ext' FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN vitamin_name LIKE 'extreme%' THEN price END AS 'extreme'
FROM vitamin) AS sel
WHERE sel.extreme IS NOT NULL;) AS sel_extreme <-- line 9

CROSS JOIN

(SELECT sel.regular as 'reg' FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN vitamin_name NOT LIKE 'extreme%' THEN price END AS 'regular'
FROM vitamin) AS sel
WHERE sel.regular IS NOT NULL;) AS sel_regular;

END
```

Comment: Remove all `;` from the middle of SQL code. Only one, in `AS sel_regular;`, is legal.

Comment: I did as you said, still does not work..

Comment: Maybe you try to use BEGIN-END not in compound statement (function, procedure, trigger, etc.)?

Comment: One more error - you use wrong quote chars over aliases (`AS 'extreme'`, `AS 'regular'`, `as 'ext'`, `as 'reg'`), backticks instead single quotes must be used.

Comment: Remove the extra semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

I mean the next query can solve your problem:

```
select 
    reg.vitamin_name,
    reg.price as regular_price,
    ext.price as extreme_price
from vitamin reg
left join vitamin ext on ext.vitamin_name = concat('extreme ', reg.vitamin_name)
where reg.vitamin_name NOT LIKE 'extreme%'
union -- add vitamins without regular form
select 
    vitamin_name,
    null,
    price as extreme_price
from vitamin ext
where vitamin_name LIKE 'extreme%' 
    and not exists (
        select vitamin_name from vitamin reg where ext.vitamin_name = concat('extreme ', reg.vitamin_name)
    )
;
```

Result from [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=908c0650ee6412b5c19d8e05b30f800b&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb):

```
+================+===============+===============+
| vitamin_name   | regular_price | extreme_price |
+================+===============+===============+
| pill 1         | 5             | 10            |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| pill 2         | 10            | 20            |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| pill 3         | 13            | (null)        |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| extreme pill 4 | (null)        | 200           |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+
```